# working on android studio code without android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, vim, sdk

I am trying to help develop some code that was made using android studio. I have a pretty old laptop and when I try to run android studio it freezes.

I figured that since android studio is just an IDE I should be able to work on the code using vim. However, I've reached a point where I need to change the SDK path in project settings. I have no idea how to do this (and am also a little hazy on what it is).

My questions are:

1. Is working on this code feasible using vim?
2. If so, how do I change the SDK path?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK path is in your `local.properties` file at the project root.

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
# Date
sdk.dir=/path/to/your/sdk
```

and yes, you can use vim and run

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

to build the debug version.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have a local.properties file though. However, I do have a gradle.properties file. Are these the same thing or do I need to make a local.properties file?

Comment: They are not the same.